# How to deploy .net to .msixbundle

Tags: maui

I try to replace my dedicated WinUI Version of an app with the one I published from my .net MAUI project. With this command I was able to publish an MSIX file:

dotnet publish -c Release -f:net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0

Unfortunately, when I upload it to the Parnter Center to submit it to the Windows Store I get this error:

```
A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows 10/11 .msixbundle or .appxbundle. Subsequent submissions must continue to contain a Windows 10/11 .msixbundle or .appxbundle.
```

I tried adding the MsBuild parameters I used for WinUI but without success:

```
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM64"
/p:AppxBundle=Always
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI
```

How can I publish my .net MAUI project as an .msixbundle or .appxbundle?

Comment: Have you generated .msixbundle and. appxbundle files?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT my question is how I can generate those. As I wrote above, I only managed to get an .msix and didn't find a way to create a .msixbundle or an appxbundle. If you have a tutorial or a guide that would be much appreciated if you could post that.

Comment: You can try the solution in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @JianweiSun-MSFT I saw that. I managed to get it working locally but still working on integrate it into my build and release process via azure devops. There I have currently an error. I'll keep you posted once that works too.

Comment: Have you solved the error?

Comment: I did just today. I tried to add some runtime .msix to the bundle by accident. now it did work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About how to build a MSIX bundle, you can refer to [Bundle MSIX packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/bundle-msix-packages). It assumes that you have already converted your existing x86 and x64 versions of the Windows installer to MSIX packages. I tested it and .msixbundle file was created successfully.

In addition, you can also read this document about [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder?view=net-maui-7.0). It was recently updated. I also follow this step to publish a MSIX package.