# Publish unpacked MAUI app without redundant dlls

Tags: visual-studio, maui, .net-7.0

I'm trying to publish my first MAUI app. However I can't use publish option in VS, because it's an unpacked Windows application (clicking publish causes Visual Studio to crash). I can just build a release version (and it runs from exe), but my bin folder ends littered with redundant dll files (big portion of .NET 7 runtimes end up there, things like system.dll etc.) and takes almost 170MB. Is there any way for me to prepare only the necessary referenced libs and app executables (or some kind of trim)?

Comment: Maui is currently ONLY reliably deployable via PUBLISH. Even if size were not a concern, attempting to use the contents of that folder is unreliable. To confirm this, copy the folder to a new Windows installation. In which Developer tools such as VS and Maui Workload have not been installed. Odds are, it will be missing something, and crash. Eventually there will be a way to publish as a .exe file. But that still would go through a publish step; just a different way of packing it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Hope this gets fixed in the future, but packing everything from the release directory actually worked on another Windows machine (one without VS etc.). I'll probably will have to try MSIX eventually, but I'll stick to unpacked while it works. Some things (like custom fonts) don't work with unpacked apps though.

Answer (score 0):

As ToolmakerSteve said that MAUI is currently ONLY reliably deployable via PUBLISH... For MAUI, it still has many functions to be implemented.

> .NET MAUI currently only allows publishing an MSIX package. You can't yet publish a Windows executable file for distribution.

About MSIX, you can refer to this case: [How to deploy .net to .msixbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708952/how-to-deploy-net-to-msixbundle).